# What is the Might and Magic: Heroes 6 Damage Computation?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

Anyone figure out yet how damage is computed?

Heroes 5 used:

> Creature Dmg * Stack Size * (1 + (.05 * (Attacker's Attack - Target's Defense)))

Is it still the same for 6?

Comment: Defense changed in Heroes VI (%, not a flat number) so the formulas can't be the same.

Comment: %? What about the "+3 to Might Defense" buffs? Do those really mean 3% instead of a flat 3?

Comment: That is a very good question.

Comment: That formula was the same in HOMM 1, 2, and 3. I expect it was the same for 4 and 5 but never played them because HOMM stopped getting better after 3 :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a fan created [Heroes VI manual](http://forums.ubi.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/5861060878/m/5131057409) that contains all the gritty details of the damage calculation.  This is not an official manual, so no guarantee it is correct.

Essentially there are two calculations:

> Raw Damage = Creature Damage * Stack Size * Attack Modifier

Creature Damage and Stack Size are what you think they are.  The Attack Modifier is a separate calculation based upon the hero's Might or Magic Attack value, depending upon the type of damage the creature inflicts.  The Raw Damage is calculated as a range, due to the Creature Damage not being a fixed number.

The second calculation brings in the defense of the stack being attacked:

> Final Damage = Raw Damage * (100% - Resistance %) * Misc Modifiers

The Misc Modifiers are bonuses given by spells, skills or artifacts (i.e. friendly creatures' ranged attacks deal 8% more damage).  Resistance % is calculated in a similar manner to the Attack Modifier using the defending stack's and hero's Might Defense or Magic Defense.

Final Damage is also a range (as Raw Damage was) and the calculation then picks a random integer out of that range for the actual damage caused by the attack.

As to your comment question regarding +3 Might Defense, that does mean +3 to the the Might Defense value, which is turned into a percentage during the Resistance % calculation.